# PHP - FPDI is failing to open existing PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

FPDI is failing to load existing PDF. How to fix it?

[image]

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/fpdi/fpdi.php');
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile( APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/fpdi/en.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');
```

// initiate FPDI

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
```

// add a page

```
$pdf->AddPage();
```

// set the source file

```
$pdf->setSourceFile("PdfDocument.pdf");
```

// import page 1

```
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
```

// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm

```
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);
```

// now write some text above the imported page

```
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Thanks. it works but i needed to make sure: `$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();`